# Python File Moving Problems

Tags: python

i'm trying to code a patch programs with python to move translation files into the game.
i was able to make a program to select the file, but i'm suffering to move that selected file to the designated destination.
it says that python could not find the file "files", but i couldnt find the solution how to make it read the file.

```
import shutil
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

list_file = []
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/",\
                 title = "Select file")

if files == '':
    messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Add the file.")

destination =  r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\I Wanna Maker\locale'

shutil.move("files", "destination")
```

Comment: Why did you quote `files` and `destination` when calling `shutil.move`? Presumably you wanted the strings in the variables of those names, but by quoting them, you passed the literal strings `"files"` and `"destination"`, not the value of the variables. Surely you just wanted `shutil.move(files, destination)`?

Comment: i also tried  `shutil.move(files,destination)` , but it says "path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not tuple".

Comment: I suggest you `print(files)` and `print(destination)` and see what's in them. I'm guessing `askopenfilenames` (which, based on the name, likely allows the user to select multiple files, where `askopenfilename` only allows them to select one) returns a `tuple` of the filenames selected (which might be a `tuple` containing only one thing, but still a `tuple`). Maybe use `askopenfilename` instead?

Comment: @ShadowRanger is correct, see here https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile

Comment: i tried two of them, and it printed `('C:/Users/k2i12/Downloads/test.txt',)` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\I Wanna Maker\locale` . i think error happens because of the `('    ',)` , but i'm not sure how to remove it

Comment: @DMDiamond: That's why I suggested `askopenfilename` (no `s`) instead; if it's only getting one item, it shouldn't wrap in a `tuple`. You could do `files[0]` to get only the first selected file (it's a `tuple`, so you can just index it), or loop over `for file in files:` and individually process each one, but it sounds like you only want one, so only ask for one.